# Database Project - Post Deployment - Static Data - XML

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, database-project

I am trying to deploy static data (contained in xml files) with my database project.

I have seen a few examples of doing so using `SQLCMD :r` but cannot get it to work in my VS2012 project - it appears to treat it as a literal string.

I have an xml file (myxml.xml) located in the same folder as the Post Deployment Script - and am trying to load the xml file into an xml variable as below:

```
declare @xml xml = '
:r /.myxml.xml
'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: AFAIk, you can execute SQLCMD scripts using xp_cmdshell. So it would be something like exec master..xp_cmdshell 'sqlcmd {something}'. You can't stuff your file sontents to a variable just by writing SQLCMD into it.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Ozren's comment, you can't load an XML file directly into a post-deploy script like this. Post-deploy scripts are designed to call/include the files specified in the script.

```
:r .\MySQLFile.sql --will import contents of MySQLFile.sql into the T-SQL script for release.
```

You may have some success with the tips over at https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/ .  There are some tips/tricks for handling text files at that link.